# Distance from line to point less than

Tags: distance

I have two layers of data: a line layer containing information about roads (including a column for the type of road, such as "A" or "B") and a point layer containing information about settlements (including columns for the name of the settlement and the population in the year 2000). I would like to calculate the total population in 2000 who lived within settlements that were less than 300 meters from roads of type "A" and "B."
IN QGIS

Comment: This sounds like homework.  You also don't include which software you're using.

Comment: I am a begginer. I hope that is allowed. @mikewatt

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, you can use the "Join Attributes by Location" tool to combine the information from the line layer and the point layer.

First, make sure both layers are loaded in QGIS and are in the same projection.
Go to the "Vector" menu and select "Data Management Tools" then "Join Attributes by Location."
In the "Join Attributes by Location" dialog box, select the point layer as the "Target vector layer" and the line layer as the "Join vector layer."
Set the "Geometric predicate" to "are within distance of" and enter "300" in the "Distance" field.
Select the "Type" column in the "Join field" and select "Name" and "Population 2000" columns in the "Target field"
Click "OK" to run the analysis.
Once the analysis is complete, a new layer will be created containing the combined information from both layers. To calculate the total population in 2000 who lived within settlements that were less than 300 meters from roads of type "A" and "B", you can use the "Select by Expression" tool and then select the "Population 2000" column, and sum the values of the selected features.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!